# Why trees aren't showing up in Blender

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm new to asking questions online! I've been trying to figure things out on my own, but this time I cannot figure out why the trees wouldn't render even if they are unrestricted or visible. What am I doing wrong? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: not sure just by looking at those pictures, maybe something layer related, if you could share the file it'd be much easier to check.

Comment: Okay, I will upload the file now. Another thing to figure out.

Comment: you can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ it's made to host blends related to stackexchange questions.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ib034p3w8qs3hqk/OutHausBackground.blend?dl=0 I created a link anyway, thanks

Comment: Let me know if the file is working or not

Comment: it is, it is, I answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you added, or I guess when the particle system for the leaves is generated, under the particle tab in the render section, the emitter checkbox is unchecked, turn that back on, and your trunks will begin showing again.

[image: particle tab]

This setting here

Comment: no problem hope you find stackexchange useful!

Comment: I do, I am comfortable asking for help now